# Multiple Selects in MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, select, phpmyadmin

Is it possible to order the results from a multiple `SELECT` queries in MySQL?

```
SELECT (
SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM `Bookings` WHERE
PickUpDate between Date1 And Date2 And `Driver`= Drivers) AS Total_Jobs,
(
SELECT Sum(`Value`) FROM `Bookings` WHERE
PickUpDate between Date1 And Date2 And `Driver`= Drivers) AS Total_Value,
(
SELECT Total_Jobs * 5 ) AS Fiver_Value,
(
SELECT Total_Value - Fiver_Value   ) AS Payment_Due
```

This calculates weekly Pay for a Driver. I have a list of 14 Drivers and I want to show the results from all 14 Drivers in the one Query.

Result I get :

```
Total_Jobs  Total_Value Fiver_Value Payment_Due
18          617         90          527
```

Comment: The result you get is just one record. How do you expect to order this?

Comment: Please add sample data as text to your question or sqlfiddle.

Comment: Sorry Self thought MySQL for my own business - This is a Database of jobs for Drivers with all the details of their pickup including date and time, Value of job etc, Im trying to write it so I can calculate all the drivers wages in the one script.

Comment: I want to replace the Variable Drivers with this `Driver` IN ('Driver1','Driver2','Driver3) to include all Drivers currently 14 individuals im using PHPMYADMIN and wrote a stored procedure with the Variable for Date1, Date2 and a list of Drivers that I can selcet just one driver from

Comment: apologies if not explaining this correctly

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All those selects are just plain wrong - you need to read up on sql aggregation functions. The query should look more like this

```
select driverid, count(*) as total_jobs, sum(value),
count(*) * 5 as fiver_value, sum(value) - (count(*) * 5) as paymen_due
from bookings
where PickUpDate between Date1 And Date2
group by driverid
```

You could help yourself by adding sample data as text to the question or to sqlfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNION if the multiple selects have the same fields and later set the order.
    SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT a FROM t1 WHERE a=10 AND B=1 ORDER BY a LIMIT 10)
        UNION
    (SELECT a FROM t2 WHERE a=11 AND B=2 ORDER BY a LIMIT 10);
    ORDER by a